# Aptitude wants to remove hundreds of packages when I try to install wine

Tags: package-management, wine, aptitude

I wanted to install Wine (doesn't matter whether it will be stable, development or staging), following the steps from the official [website](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu), but I get the following

```
sudo aptitude install winehq-staging
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  glib-networking:i386{a} gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386{ab} i965-va-driver:i386{a} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} libasound2:i386{ab} libasound2-plugins:i386{a} libasyncns0:i386{a} libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386{a} 
  libatk1.0-0:i386{a} libatspi2.0-0:i386{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a} libavahi-common-data:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} libblkid1:i386{ab} libcairo-gobject2:i386{a} libcairo2:i386{a} libcap2:i386{a} 
  libcapi20-3{a} libcdparanoia0:i386{a} libcolord2:i386{a} libcups2:i386{a} libdatrie1:i386{a} libdb5.3:i386{ab} libdbus-1-3:i386{a} libegl1:i386{a} libepoxy0:i386{a} libexif12:i386{a} libflac8:i386{a} 
  libfontconfig1:i386{a} libfreetype6:i386{ab} libgd3:i386{a} libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386{a} libglib2.0-0:i386{ab} libgmp10:i386{a} libgnutls30:i386{a} libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-port12:i386{a} 
  libgpm2:i386{a} libgraphite2-3:i386{a} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{a} libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386{ab} libgstreamer1.0-0:i386{ab} libgtk-3-0:i386{ab} libharfbuzz0b:i386{ab} 
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} libhogweed4:i386{a} libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} libidn2-0:i386{a} libieee1284-3:i386{a} libjack-jackd2-0:i386{a} 
  libjbig0:i386{a} libjson-glib-1.0-0:i386{a} libk5crypto3:i386{a} libkeyutils1:i386{ab} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} libkrb5-3:i386{a} libkrb5support0:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} libltdl7:i386{a} 
  libmount1:i386{ab} libncurses5:i386{ab} libnettle6:i386{a} libodbc1{a} libodbc1:i386{a} libogg0:i386{a} libopenal1:i386{a} libopus0:i386{a} liborc-0.4-0:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} libpango-1.0-0:i386{a} 
  libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386{a} libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386{a} libpcap0.8:i386{a} libpixman-1-0:i386{a} libpng16-16:i386{a} libproxy1v5:i386{a} libpulse0:i386{ab} librest-0.7-0:i386{a} libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libsamplerate0:i386{a} libsane1:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} libsdl2-2.0-0{a} libsdl2-2.0-0:i386{a} libsndfile1:i386{a} libsndio6.1:i386{a} 
  libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386{a} libsoup2.4-1:i386{a} libspeexdsp1:i386{a} libsqlite3-0:i386{a} libssl1.1:i386{a} libsystemd0:i386{ab} libtasn1-6:i386{a} libthai0:i386{a} libtheora0:i386{a} libtiff5:i386{ab} 
  libunistring2:i386{a} libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} libuuid1:i386{ab} libva-drm2:i386{a} libva-x11-2:i386{a} libva2:i386{a} libvisual-0.4-0:i386{a} libvorbis0a:i386{a} libvorbisenc2:i386{a} libvulkan1:i386{a} 
  libwayland-client0:i386{a} libwayland-cursor0:i386{a} libwayland-egl1-mesa:i386{a} libwebp6:i386{a} libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} libwrap0:i386{a} libxcb-render0:i386{a} libxcb-shm0:i386{a} 
  libxcb-xfixes0:i386{a} libxkbcommon0:i386{a} libxpm4:i386{a} mesa-va-drivers:i386{a} va-driver-all:i386{a} wine-staging{a} wine-staging-amd64{a} wine-staging-i386:i386{a} winehq-staging 
0 packages upgraded, 128 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 77.4 MB of archives. After unpacking 555 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsystemd0 : Breaks: libsystemd0:i386 (!= 237-3ubuntu10) but 237-3ubuntu7 is to be installed
 libsystemd0:i386 : Breaks: libsystemd0 (!= 237-3ubuntu7) but 237-3ubuntu10 is installed
 libgtk-3-0 : Breaks: libgtk-3-0:i386 (!= 3.22.30-1ubuntu1) but 3.22.29-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libgtk-3-0:i386 : Breaks: libgtk-3-0 (!= 3.22.29-3ubuntu1) but 3.22.30-1ubuntu1 is installed
 libasound2-data : Breaks: libasound2:i386 (< 1.1.3-5ubuntu0.1) but 1.1.3-5 is to be installed
 libmount1 : Breaks: libmount1:i386 (!= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libmount1:i386 : Breaks: libmount1 (!= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1 is installed
 libncurses5 : Breaks: libncurses5:i386 (!= 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04) but 6.1-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libncurses5:i386 : Depends: libtinfo5:i386 (= 6.1-1ubuntu1) but 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04 is installed
                    Breaks: libncurses5 (!= 6.1-1ubuntu1) but 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04 is installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base : Breaks: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 (!= 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1) but 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 : Breaks: gstreamer1.0-plugins-base (!= 1.14.0-2ubuntu1) but 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 is installed
 libblkid1 : Breaks: libblkid1:i386 (!= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libblkid1:i386 : Breaks: libblkid1 (!= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1 is installed
 libtiff5 : Breaks: libtiff5:i386 (!= 4.0.9-5) but 4.0.9-4ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libtiff5:i386 : Breaks: libtiff5 (!= 4.0.9-4ubuntu1) but 4.0.9-5 is installed
 libpulse0 : Breaks: libpulse0:i386 (!= 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1) but 1:11.1-1ubuntu7 is to be installed
 libpulse0:i386 : Breaks: libpulse0 (!= 1:11.1-1ubuntu7) but 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1 is installed
 libuuid1 : Breaks: libuuid1:i386 (!= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libuuid1:i386 : Breaks: libuuid1 (!= 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3) but 2.31.1-0.4ubuntu3.1 is installed
 libkeyutils1 : Breaks: libkeyutils1:i386 (!= 1.5.9-9.2ubuntu2) but 1.5.9-9.2ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libkeyutils1:i386 : Breaks: libkeyutils1 (!= 1.5.9-9.2ubuntu1) but 1.5.9-9.2ubuntu2 is installed
 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 : Breaks: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (!= 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1) but 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (!= 1.14.0-2ubuntu1) but 1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 is installed
 libdb5.3 : Breaks: libdb5.3:i386 (!= 5.3.28-13.1ubuntu1) but 5.3.28-13.1 is to be installed
 libdb5.3:i386 : Breaks: libdb5.3 (!= 5.3.28-13.1) but 5.3.28-13.1ubuntu1 is installed
 libasound2 : Breaks: libasound2:i386 (!= 1.1.3-5ubuntu0.1) but 1.1.3-5 is to be installed
 libasound2:i386 : Breaks: libasound2 (!= 1.1.3-5) but 1.1.3-5ubuntu0.1 is installed
 libfreetype6 : Breaks: libfreetype6:i386 (!= 2.8.1-2ubuntu2) but 2.8.1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libfreetype6:i386 : Breaks: libfreetype6 (!= 2.8.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.8.1-2ubuntu2 is installed
 libharfbuzz0b : Breaks: libharfbuzz0b:i386 (!= 1.7.2-1ubuntu1) but 1.7.2-1 is to be installed
 libharfbuzz0b:i386 : Breaks: libharfbuzz0b (!= 1.7.2-1) but 1.7.2-1ubuntu1 is installed
 libgstreamer1.0-0 : Breaks: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (!= 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1) but 1.14.0-1 is to be installed
 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libgstreamer1.0-0 (!= 1.14.0-1) but 1.14.1-1~ubuntu18.04.1 is installed
 libglib2.0-0 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0:i386 (!= 2.56.1-2ubuntu1) but 2.56.0-4ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libglib2.0-0:i386 : Breaks: libglib2.0-0 (!= 2.56.0-4ubuntu1) but 2.56.1-2ubuntu1 is installed
open: 297; closed: 2888; defer: 45; conflict: 96                                                                                                                                                                  oThe following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:                          
1)      glib-networking:i386 [Not Installed]                                         
2)      gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 [Not Installed]                               
3)      libasound2:i386 [Not Installed]                                              
4)      libasound2-plugins:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
5)      libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
6)      libatk1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                             
7)      libatspi2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
8)      libavahi-client3:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
9)      libblkid1:i386 [Not Installed]                                               
10)     libcairo-gobject2:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
11)     libcairo2:i386 [Not Installed]                                               
12)     libcolord2:i386 [Not Installed]                                              
13)     libcups2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                
14)     libdb5.3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                
15)     libdbus-1-3:i386 [Not Installed]                                             
16)     libfontconfig1:i386 [Not Installed]                                          
17)     libfreetype6:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
18)     libgd3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                  
19)     libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
20)     libglib2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
21)     libgphoto2-6:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
22)     libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                        
23)     libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                          
24)     libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
25)     libgtk-3-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                              
26)     libharfbuzz0b:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
27)     libjson-glib-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
28)     libkeyutils1:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
29)     libkrb5-3:i386 [Not Installed]                                               
30)     libldap-2.4-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
31)     libmount1:i386 [Not Installed]                                               
32)     libncurses5:i386 [Not Installed]                                             
33)     libopenal1:i386 [Not Installed]                                              
34)     libpango-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                          
35)     libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                     
36)     libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
37)     libpulse0:i386 [Not Installed]                                               
38)     librest-0.7-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
39)     libsane1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                
40)     libsasl2-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                              
41)     libsasl2-modules-db:i386 [Not Installed]                                     
42)     libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
43)     libsndio6.1:i386 [Not Installed]                                             
44)     libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 [Not Installed]                                      
45)     libsoup2.4-1:i386 [Not Installed]                                            
46)     libsystemd0:i386 [Not Installed]                                             
47)     libtheora0:i386 [Not Installed]                                              
48)     libtiff5:i386 [Not Installed]                                                
49)     libuuid1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                
50)     wine-staging [Not Installed]                                                 
51)     wine-staging-i386:i386 [Not Installed]                                       
52)     winehq-staging [Not Installed]                                               

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                                   
53)     libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386
54)     libopenal1:i386 recommends libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.16)                       
55)     wine-staging-i386:i386 recommends libcairo2:i386 (>= 1.2.4)                  
56)     wine-staging-i386:i386 recommends libcups2:i386 (>= 1.4.0)                   
57)     wine-staging-i386:i386 recommends libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.9.14)               
58)     wine-staging-i386:i386 recommends libfontconfig1:i386 (>= 2.12)              
59)     wine-staging-i386:i386 recommends libfreetype6:i386 (>= 2.2.1)               
60)     wine-staging-i386:i386 recommends libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2)      
61)     wine-staging-i386:i386 recommends libgtk-3-0:i386 (>= 3.0.0)                 
62)     wine-staging-i386:i386 recommends libkrb5-3:i386 (>= 1.6.dfsg.2)             
63)     wine-staging-i386:i386 recommends libncurses5:i386 (>= 6)                    
64)     wine-staging-i386:i386 recommends libsane1:i386 (>= 1.0.24)                  
65)     wine-staging-i386:i386 recommends libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.0.8)              
66)     wine-staging-i386:i386 recommends libtiff5:i386 (>= 4.0.3)                   



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
```

If I go with Y, I just get

```
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

If on the other hadn I go with n, I am prompted with another choice

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:                                                                  
1)      cheese [3.28.0-1ubuntu1 (bionic, now)]                                                        
2)      evince [3.28.2-1 (bionic, now)]                                                               
3)      gnome-control-center [1:3.28.1-0ubuntu1.18.04.2 (now)]                                        
4)      gnome-video-effects [0.4.3-1ubuntu1 (bionic, now)]                                            
5)      gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad [1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 (now)]                                
6)      gstreamer1.0-plugins-base [1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 (now)]                               
7)      gstreamer1.0-plugins-good [1.14.1-1ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 (now)]                               
8)      indicator-bluetooth [0.0.6+17.10.20170605-0ubuntu3 (bionic, now)]                             
9)      libcheese-gtk25 [3.28.0-1ubuntu1 (bionic, now)]                                               
10)     libcheese8 [3.28.0-1ubuntu1 (bionic, now)]                                                    
11)     libevview3-3 [3.28.2-1 (bionic, now)]                                                         
12)     rhythmbox [3.4.2-4ubuntu1 (bionic, now)]                                                      
13)     rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar [0.18.0-1 (bionic, now)]                                 
14)     rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist [3.4.2-4ubuntu1 (bionic, now)]                                     
15)     rhythmbox-plugins [3.4.2-4ubuntu1 (bionic, now)]                                              
16)     totem [3.26.0-0ubuntu6 (bionic, now)]                                                         
17)     totem-plugins [3.26.0-0ubuntu6 (bionic, now)]                                                 
18)     unity-control-center [15.04.0+18.04.20180216-0ubuntu1 (bionic, now)]                          

      Install the following packages:                                                                 
19)     libmate-panel-applet-4-1 [1.20.1-0ubuntu1 (bionic)]                                           
20)     mate-power-manager [1.20.1-0ubuntu1 (bionic)]                                                 
21)     mate-power-manager-common [1.20.1-0ubuntu1 (bionic)]                                          
22)     mupdf [1.12.0+ds1-1 (bionic)]                                                                 

      Keep the following packages at their current version:                                           
23)     glib-networking:i386 [Not Installed]                                                          
24)     gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 [Not Installed]                                                
25)     libasound2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                               
26)     libasound2-plugins:i386 [Not Installed]                                                       
27)     libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                       
28)     libatk1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                              
29)     libatspi2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                            
30)     libavahi-client3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                         
31)     libblkid1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                
32)     libcairo-gobject2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                        
33)     libcairo2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                
34)     libcolord2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                               
35)     libcups2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                 
36)     libdb5.3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                 
37)     libdbus-1-3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                              
38)     libfontconfig1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                           
39)     libfreetype6:i386 [Not Installed]                                                             
40)     libgd3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                   
41)     libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                       
42)     libglib2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                             
43)     libgphoto2-6:i386 [Not Installed]                                                             
44)     libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                         
45)     libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                           
46)     libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                        
47)     libgtk-3-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                               
48)     libharfbuzz0b:i386 [Not Installed]                                                            
49)     libjson-glib-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                       
50)     libkeyutils1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                             
51)     libkrb5-3:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                
52)     libldap-2.4-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                            
53)     libmount1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                
54)     libncurses5:i386 [Not Installed]                                                              
55)     libopenal1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                               
56)     libpango-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                           
57)     libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                      
58)     libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                        
59)     libpulse0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                
60)     librest-0.7-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                            
61)     libsane1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                 
62)     libsasl2-2:i386 [Not Installed]                                                               
63)     libsasl2-modules-db:i386 [Not Installed]                                                      
64)     libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                            
65)     libsndio6.1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                              
66)     libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                       
67)     libsoup2.4-1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                             
68)     libsystemd0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                              
69)     libtheora0:i386 [Not Installed]                                                               
70)     libtiff5:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                 
71)     libuuid1:i386 [Not Installed]                                                                 
72)     wine-staging [Not Installed]                                                                  
73)     wine-staging-i386:i386 [Not Installed]                                                        
74)     winehq-staging [Not Installed]                                                                

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:                                                    
75)     gnome-bluetooth recommends gnome-control-center | unity-control-center                        
76)     rhythmbox-data recommends rhythmbox                                                           
77)     libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386                 
78)     indicator-datetime recommends unity-control-center (>= 14.04.3) | gnome-control-center        
79)     indicator-session recommends unity-control-center | gnome-control-center | mate-control-center
80)     libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-base                                       
81)     libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-good                                       
82)     libopenal1:i386 recommends libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.16)                                        
83)     wine-staging-i386:i386 recommends libncurses5:i386 (>= 6)                                     
84)     libspice-server1 recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-base                                         
85)     libspice-server1 recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-good                                         
86)     libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-good                                     
87)     libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-base                           
88)     gnome-online-accounts recommends gnome-control-center (>= 3.6.1)                              
89)     gnome-shell recommends gnome-control-center                                                   
90)     unity recommends unity-control-center                                                         
91)     unity-session recommends rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist                                           
92)     unity-services recommends indicator-bluetooth                                                 



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

which, when accepted with Y, takes me to

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmate-panel-applet-4-1{a} mate-power-manager{a} mate-power-manager-common{a} mupdf{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  activity-log-manager{u} apache2-bin{u} apg{u} cheese{a} cheese-common{u} evince{a} evince-common{u} freepats{u} gir1.2-rb-3.0{u} gir1.2-totem-1.0{u} gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0{u} gnome-control-center{a} 
  gnome-control-center-faces{u} gnome-user-share{u} gnome-video-effects{a} grilo-plugins-0.3-base{u} gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0{u} gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad{a} gstreamer1.0-plugins-base{a} 
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-good{a} gstreamer1.0-x{u} indicator-bluetooth{a} libapache2-mod-dnssd{u} libapr1{u} libaprutil1{u} libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3{u} libaprutil1-ldap{u} libcdparanoia0{u} libcheese-gtk25{a} 
  libcheese8{a} libcolord-gtk1{u} libde265-0{u} libdmapsharing-3.0-2{u} libdv4{u} libevdocument3-4{u} libevview3-3{a} libfluidsynth1{u} libgeonames-common{u} libgeonames0{u} libgmime-3.0-0{u} 
  libgom-1.0-0{u} libgpod-common{u} libgpod4{u} libgrilo-0.3-0{u} libgssdp-1.0-3{u} libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0{u} libgupnp-1.0-4{u} libgupnp-igd-1.0-4{u} libgxps2{u} libiec61883-0{u} liblilv-0-0{u} 
  liblua5.3-0{u} libmediaart-2.0-0{u} libmjpegutils-2.1-0{u} libmms0{u} libmodplug1{u} libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0{u} libmplex2-2.1-0{u} libnice10{u} libnm-gtk0{u} libnss-myhostname{u} libofa0{u} 
  librhythmbox-core10{u} libsbc1{u} libserd-0-0{u} libsgutils2-2{u} libsord-0-0{u} libsoundtouch1{u} libspandsp2{u} libspectre1{u} libsratom-0-0{u} libsrtp2-1{u} libtimezonemap-data{u} libtimezonemap1{u} 
  libtotem-plparser-common{u} libtotem-plparser18{u} libtotem0{u} libunity-control-center1{u} libv4l-0{u} libv4lconvert0{u} libvisual-0.4-0{u} libvo-aacenc0{u} libwhoopsie-preferences0{u} 
  libwildmidi-config{u} libwildmidi2{u} libzbar0{u} media-player-info{u} python3-mako{u} python3-markupsafe{u} realmd{u} rhythmbox{a} rhythmbox-data{u} rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar{a} 
  rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist{a} rhythmbox-plugins{a} totem{a} totem-common{u} totem-plugins{a} ubuntu-system-service{u} unity-control-center{a} whoopsie-preferences{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 101 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 21.5 MB of archives. After unpacking 57.5 MB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]
```

So it wants to remove 101 packages and install 4 other ones which don't seem related to wine-staging. Also some of the packages that it wants to remove seem important to me - like ubuntu-system-service. Is it safe to proceed ot this will break my system?

I recently upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04 and I have also updated the kernel to 4.17.9-041709-generic. I am on a 64-bit system. Everything seems ok apart form the fact that sometimes after resuming from a locked screen the desktop is frozen, so I have to restart. I have looked for simialr issues on the internet, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Notice that all packages to be removed and shuffled around are 32-bit packages (`i386`). This may work on your system if it is a 64-bit system otherwise. Personally, I would keep on the safe side and forget all about installing `wine`.

Comment: I have a 64-bit system indeed. I have the feeling that this goes deeper than wine

Comment: Have you tried `wine-stable`? That installed without problems on my 64 bit 18.04 system.

Comment: Yes, same result with all three versions (stable, development, staging) of wine

Comment: `apt-cache policy` please.

Comment: 2 year old issue and 20.04.1 is available.... ?archeology

Comment: Does `sudo apt install -f` return "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded"? If you don't need i386 just remove it: `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386`

Comment: Any chance you have hw stack on your system?

Comment: Sorry guys, it is not me (OP) who has put the bounty on. I did resolve the issue, but it was after a lot of playing around, so I never figured out what actually did the trick. But it was something else that was the troublemaker. I am currently on 20.04 and wine installs and works perfectly. Do you think I can be of any help?

Comment: @user406875 Could you upload the output of `apt-get -s -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install wine` and `echo q | aptitude -s install wine` to paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me. I uninstalled a lot of packages in the process but they were installed back later on. I searched a lot on the internet and finally gave up. Today I tried to give it another go. The issue basically is a conflict of versions. The i386 package wants to use a downgraded amd64 package. Thus it gives an error. I am copying the first error below:

> libsystemd0:i386 : Breaks: libsystemd0 (!= 237-3ubuntu7) but 237-3ubuntu10 is installed

which means `libsystemd0:i386` wants `libsystemd0` version to be `237-3ubuntu7` but the currently installed version is `237-3ubuntu10`.

Now coming to the solution. You have to manually downgrade all the `amd64` packages by:

```
sudo aptitude install libsystemd0=237-3ubuntu7
```

so on...

Comment: As I said in the comment to my above post, it is not me (OP) who has put the bounty on. I did resolve the issue, but it was after a lot of playing around, so I never figured out what actually did the trick. But it was something else that was the troublemaker. All I can advise from what I remember is that I used apt-get instead of apt (as that seems to handle dependecies better) and I somehow figured out which are the main offending dependcies and fought with them. I think a few were already present so had to be reinstalled. I also see that I have been googling a lot about libasound2